# Python "double quotes" invalid syntax - with print

Tags: python, syntax, runtime-error

**code**:

```
print(f"Database has {len(result)} rows")
```

**error**:

```
print(f"Database has {len(result)} rows")
                                       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**tried** (single quote instead of double) = **same error**

Comment: which version of Python do you use?

Comment: @Matho i managed to reproduce the error in python 2.7. in python 3.8 it worked fine, so I guess he is using python 2.7

Comment: solution for python 2.7: print "Database has {0} rows".format(len(result))